# IIS doesn't download mustache files

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, mustache

my IIS (7.5) doesn't allow to download mustache files. Then I add it to extensions allowed and then js files are not downloaded. Someone knows why??
When I add to allow the download this is written in the web.config

```
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mustache" mimeType="text/html" />
  </staticContent>
```

then mustache files are downloaded but js files are not.
My application is an aspnet 4.5 one.
Thanks! Guillermo.

Comment: When you look in your browser F12 debug tools do you see the .js files being 404'd or otherwise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I ended up doing is going to the IIS and added a new MIME type BUT:

1. Did it at server level, not application nor website (I mean, first entry in the left list)
2. Didn't add it as text/html but text/template

That, made it work. Web.config was not changed at all for this.
MIME type for both website and application under the website had the MIME type as inherited (because I already added it at server level)

Comment: Thanks for this one.